# What's the difference between concurrent.futures' async and requests-futures' async in python?

Tags: python, asynchronous, concurrency, concurrent.futures

I used requests-futures to grab web page asynchronously.And my machine have multicores, so I also want to grab many websites simultaneously,then I try to use concurrent.futures, it seems concurrent.futures also provide asynchronous method,so what's the difference between concurrent.futures' async and requests-futures' async?If they are same,means I could deprecate requests-futures?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`requests-futures` is just a very small wrapper on top of `concurrent.futures`. You can see this by looking at the [source code](https://github.com/ross/requests-futures/blob/master/requests_futures/sessions.py) (With docstrings removed for brevity):

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from requests import Session
from requests.adapters import DEFAULT_POOLSIZE, HTTPAdapter

class FuturesSession(Session):

    def __init__(self, executor=None, max_workers=2, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FuturesSession, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if executor is None:
            executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_workers)
            # set connection pool size equal to max_workers if needed
            if max_workers > DEFAULT_POOLSIZE:
                adapter_kwargs = dict(pool_connections=max_workers,
                                      pool_maxsize=max_workers)
                self.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter(**adapter_kwargs))
                self.mount('http://', HTTPAdapter(**adapter_kwargs))

        self.executor = executor

    def request(self, *args, **kwargs):
        func = sup = super(FuturesSession, self).request

        background_callback = kwargs.pop('background_callback', None)
        if background_callback:
            def wrap(*args_, **kwargs_):
                resp = sup(*args_, **kwargs_)
                background_callback(self, resp)
                return resp

            func = wrap

        return self.executor.submit(func, *args, **kwargs) # This returns a concurrent.futures.Future
```

When you use `requests-futures`, you're really using `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`, which returns a `concurrent.futures.Future` when you `submit` a task to it. If it's more convenient for you to use the API provided by `requests-futures` for dealing with HTTP requests, it's ok to stick with it, and even use the objects returned by it with other methods provided by the `concurrent.futures` module.

Comment: Thx~I also want to utilize multi-core,so concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor seems better?

Comment: @leafonsword Well, for using the `requests` library, you're probably ok using `ThreadPoolExecutor`; HTTP requests are I/O-bound operations, which means the GIL will be released for most of it. If you're also trying to do CPU-bound operations concurrently, you'd definitely want to use `ProcessPoolExecutor`.